# getting my range loop to disregard the header row?

Tags: vba

I have a simple for loop that counts the amount of visible rows after an autofilter. I've done research and the consensus seems to be something like `.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.count - 1` should work, but it keeps counting the header row.

```
            On Error Resume Next

            termsfound = 0
            For Each mycell In tgtws.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.count - 1
                If IsError(mycell) = False Then
                    termsfound = termsfound + 1
                End If
            Next

            If termsfound > 0 Then
                MsgBox "Found " & termsfound & " term(s).", vbOKOnly, "Results"
            Else
            TgtWS.Rows(1).EntireRow.AutoFilter
            TgtWS.Range("A2").Select
                MsgBox "No terms found"
        End If
```

any idea why it's not working properly?

whole code:

```
Sub LOBEligibilityTermCheck()

Dim SrcWB As Workbook
Dim SrcWS As Worksheet
Dim TgtWS As Worksheet

Workbooks.Open ("M:\Final Terms.xlsx")
Workbooks.Open ("M:\daily-report.xlsx")

Set SrcWB = Workbooks("Final Terms.xlsx")
Set TgtWB = Workbooks("daily-report.xlsx")
Set SrcWS = SrcWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set TgtWS = TgtWB.Sheets(1)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    If WorksheetIsOpen("Final Terms.xlsx", "Sheet1") = False Then
        MsgBox "This macro requires the term file to be open prior to running." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
            & "The file name MUST be 'Final Terms .xlsx' and the list MUST be in a worksheet (tab) titled 'Sheet1'." _
            & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please open the file and run the macro again.", vbOKOnly, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

        lastCell = TgtWS.Range("A" & TgtWS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        TgtWS.Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
        TgtWS.Columns("E").Insert
        TgtWS.Range("E1") = "Social Security Number"
        TgtWS.Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2]="""",RC[-1],RC[-2])& """""
        TgtWS.Range("e2").AutoFill Destination:=TgtWS.Range("e2:e" & lastCell)
        TgtWS.Range("e:e").Copy
        TgtWS.Range("e:e").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        TgtWS.Range("C:D").EntireColumn.Delete
        TgtWS.Range("A1:A" & Range("AP" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=">=" & CLng(Date - 2)

        lastrowlob = LastRowIndex(TgtWS, 1)

        TgtWS.Columns("D").Insert
        TgtWS.Cells(1, 4) = "Unique Identifier"
        TgtWS.Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(lastrowlob, 4)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = "=trim(rc[-3]&right(rc[-1],4))"

        TgtWS.Columns("E").Insert
        TgtWS.Cells(1, 5) = "Eligibility Lookup"
        TgtWS.Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(lastrowlob, 5)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFNA(INDEX('[Final Terms.xlsx]Sheet1'!C13,MATCH(RC[-1],'[Final Terms.xlsx]Sheet1'!C13,0)),"""")"
        TgtWS.Rows(1).EntireRow.AutoFilter
        TgtWS.Range("E:E").Copy
        TgtWS.Range("E:E").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        TgtWS.Range("$A$1:$AO$" & lastrowlob).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlAnd
        TgtWS.Range("A2").Select

            On Error Resume Next

            termsfound = 0
            For Each mycell In tgtws.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.count - 1
                If IsError(mycell) = False Then
                    termsfound = termsfound + 1
                End If
            Next

            If termsfound > 0 Then
                MsgBox "Found " & termsfound & " term(s).", vbOKOnly, "Results"
            Else
            TgtWS.Rows(1).EntireRow.AutoFilter
            TgtWS.Range("A2").Select
                MsgBox "No terms found"
        End If


     SrcWB.Close savechanges = False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Then do minus 2? Hard to tell what's going on from this code snippet.

Comment: @dwirony just added in whole code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up `For` and `For Each`. `For` works with numbers. `For Each` does exactly what is says - for each entry in the object, it will do what you want. In your situation, you can work with row numbers, but I would go for `For Each`. The cheap solution here is to test if it the first run and skip the action, but that's not good code. Do like this instead:

```
Dim TargetRange As Range
Set TargetRange = tgtws.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Set TargetRange = TargetRange.Offset(1) ' move it down one row
Set TargetRange = TargetRange.Resize(TargetRange.Rows.Count - 1) ' make it one row shorter

For Each mycell In TargetRange
    '...
Next
```

I have copied your range definition and put it in a variable. Then the range is moved one step down, and then resized. Put a `TargetRange.Select` in your code at a suitable location - it's a quick way to check the result while debugging.